I can't get any PDF uploads to read
The app is supposed to read multiple PDFs but I can't get even a single PDF to work because of this issue. Any help is appreciated.
I received the error:
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'

And I received this traceback error:
File "c:\Users\XANDER\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 600, in _run_script
        exec(code, module.__dict__)
    File "C:\Users\XANDER\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Projects\app.py", line 89, in <module>
        main()
    File "C:\Users\XANDER\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Projects\app.py", line 83, in main
        raw_text = get_pdf_text(pdf_docs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\XANDER\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Projects\app.py", line 21, in get_pdf_text
        pdf_reader=PdfReader(pdf)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "c:\Users\XANDER\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pypdf\_reader.py", line 127, in __init__
        self.read(stream)
    File "c:\Users\XANDER\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pypdf\_reader.py", line 538, in read
        self._basic_validation(stream)
    File "c:\Users\XANDER\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pypdf\_reader.py", line 597, in _basic_validation
        stream.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^

import streamlit as st
from pypdf import PdfReader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
import os

from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings
import google.generativeai as genai
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_google_genai import ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

genai.configure(api_key=os.getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY"))

def get_pdf_text(pdf_docs):
    text=""
    for pdf in pdf_docs:
        pdf_reader=PdfReader(pdf)
        for page in pdf_reader.pages:
            text+=page.extract_text()
    return text

def get_text_chunks(text):
    text_splitter=RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=10000, chunk_overlap=1000)
    chunks=text_splitter.split_text(text)
    return chunks

def get_vector_store(text_chunks):
    embeddings=GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001")
    vector_store=FAISS.from_texts(text_chunks, embedding=embeddings)
    vector_store.save_local("faiss_index")

def get_conversational_chain():
    prompt_template="""
    Answer the question as detailed as possible from the provided context, make sure to provide all the details, if the answer is not in
    the provided context just say, "answer is not available in the context", don't provide the wrong answer \n\n
    Context:\n {context}?\n
    Question:\n{queestion}\n

    Answer:
    """

    model=ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-pro", temperature=0.3)

    prompt=PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"])
    chain=load_qa_chain(model, chain_type="stuff", prompt=prompt)
    return chain

def user_input(user_question):
    embeddings=GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001")

    new_db = FAISS.load_local("faiss_index", embeddings)
    docs = new_db.similarity_search(user_question)

    chain = get_conversational_chain


    response = chain(
        {"input_documents":docs, "question": user_question}
        , return_only_outputs=True
    )

    print(response)
    st.write("Reply: ", response["output_text"])

def main():
    st.set_page_config("Chat With Multiple PDFs")
    st.header("Chat with Multiple PDFs using Gemini ‍♀️")

    user_question = st.text_input("Ask a Question from the PDF Files")

    if user_question:
        user_input(user_question)

    with st.sidebar:
        st.title("Menu:")
        pdf_docs = st.file_uploader("Upload your PDF Files and Click on Submit & Process")
        if st.button("Submit & Process"):
            with st.spinner("Processing..."):
                raw_text = get_pdf_text(pdf_docs)
                text_chunks = get_text_chunks(raw_text)
                get_vector_store(text_chunks)
                st.success("Done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    

I was originally using PyPdf2, but changed to  PyPDF as I heard it may have caused this issue. I expected and hoped it was a simple fix.

Please post the full traceback of the error.

I added the traceback error. Thanks for your help in advance.

st.file_uploader() is just returning a single UploadedFile object. So you're looping over the lines in the PDF document, not over a list of documents.
Use the accept_multiple_files option to allow the user to select multiple files, then it will return a list.
pdf_docs = st.file_uploader(
    "Upload your PDF Files and Click on Submit & Process", 
    accept_multiple_files=True)

